# How to control EventLevel for a ETW event triggered through EventSource?

Tags: c#, etw

I have this class for triggering ETW events:

```
public sealed class EventSourceWriter : EventSource
{
    public static EventSourceWriter Logger = new EventSourceWriter();

    [Event(1, Version = 0, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Log(string Log)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, Log);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the `EventLevel` on top of the `Log` method as attribute value. Is there a way I can set it dynamically to log different EventLevels to same Event?

The idea is to see all generic logs on same table as output when an agent captures the `ETW` events.

Comment: In .NET 4.6 they added support for [dynamic events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2015/10/02/dynamically-defined-events-in-eventsource-v4-6.aspx). Note that there is a guidance document linked there which says "we still recommend using the ‘contract based’ approach whenever that is possible."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mike-z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517852/mike-z) has pointed out for .NET 4.6 you might archive that by using [dynamic events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2015/10/02/dynamically-defined-events-in-eventsource-v4-6.aspx), but in this case those events won't be included into the manifest, and not all of ETW tools have been updated to support self-describing events yet.

But generally you are writing your EventSource class like this to archive that:

```
public sealed class EventSourceWriter : EventSource
{
    public static EventSourceWriter Logger = new EventSourceWriter();

    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void LogInformational(string message)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, message);
    }

    [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Warning)]
    public void LogWarning(string message)
    {
        WriteEvent(2, message);
    }

    [Event(3, Level = EventLevel.Error)]
    public void LogError(string message)
    {
        WriteEvent(3, message);
    }
}
```